# Webservices / dynamic class generation / flow

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, wsdl, jax-ws

My question probably sounds all wrong since I'm not sure what to ask exactly. I'm very new to web services in general but get a very high level idea. I'm looking at some code where the classes/methods are annotated and exposed for service calls.

The `wsimport` command can be used to call the `http://.....?wsdl` which it looks like dynamically generates these the client classes. I do not see a specific WSDL file so i'm guessing the JAX-WS is creating and sending the client source code to the client whcih downloads it and compiles it to the respective classes.

I notice some difference in the client generated class and the original server side class such as the missing `toString()` method and `equals()` method. Trying to read about this suggested something about custommized JAXB bindings and stuff. My questions are:

1. Does anyone know and can share information that gives a better
   understanding of the kind of process I'm seeing. i.e. how the
   annotated methods are magically appearing on the client side as part
   of their respective classes?
2. Regarding the JAXB binding most of the websites begin from an
   existing WSDL. How does this fit into my current problem?

Thanks

Comment: The classes will not necessarily match on the client and server side. All they need is some correspondence to the XML in the SOAP messages. So if there is a <date> field in the XML message, there will probably be a date property in both java classes but for that property one end might use a java Date object and the other might use a Calendar or some custom representation of a date or even a string. The code on each end will have to deal with whatever is used. Just remember, the real root of the data is the SOAP message string.

Comment: Answering your question might take several chapters in a good book. Start with these resources:http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html, http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnazg.html, http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbay.html, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-jax/section3.html